# how to convert from QGLFormat to QString

Tags: qt

```
QGLWidget w = new QGLWidget();
w->makeCurrent();
QString str = w->format(); //error:no suitable conversion from  QGLFormat to QString
```

in the above code :

> w->format(); //returns QGLFormat

return type is "[QGLFormat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglformat.html)" but I want to covert it to "[QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html)", how do I do that.

Comment: Get each parameter and write it to a string. Nobody needs to do that, so there is no special function for that.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a `QString` for display to the user, or do you want to see it in the debug output (i.e. `qDebug() << w->format();`). Please edit the question to clarify, because the answers will be different based on that.

Comment: I want to convert it to a QString for display to the user, not to see in the debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGLFormat` contains many attributes, so in order to convert it into a `QString`, you would need to concatenate required attributes into a single string.

```
QGLFormat format = ...
QString str = "Info:\n";

str += "version:" QString::number(format.majorVersion()) + "\n";
str += "red buffer size:" + QString::number(format.redBufferSize()) + "\n";
str += "green buffer size:" + QString::number(format.greenBufferSize()) + "\n";
str += "blue buffer size:" + QString::number(format.blueBufferSize());

// Here you can use 'str' as a QString
```